# ¿Cómo combinar dos listas de objetos en java8?

Tags: android, java-8, lambda

Tengo el siguiente clase

```
public class Banner {

    private String ref;
    private String src;
    private String lang;


    public Banner(String ref, String src) {
        this.ref = ref;
        this.src = src;
        this.lang = "en";
    }

    public Banner(String ref, String src, String lng) {
        this.ref = ref;
        this.src = src;
        this.lang = lng;
    }

    public String getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public String getSrc() {
        return src;
    }

    public void setSrc(String src) {
        this.src = src;
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Banner{" +
                "ref='" + ref + '\'' +
                ", src='" + src + '\'' +
                ", lang='" + lang + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Con los datos:

```
List<Banner> myCollectionA = new ArrayList<>();
myCollectionA.add(new Banner("r01", "way one", "en"));
myCollectionA.add(new Banner("r01", "camino uno", "es"));
myCollectionA.add(new Banner("r02", "camino dos", "es"));
myCollectionA.add(new Banner("r03", "camino tres", "es"));
myCollectionA.add(new Banner("r03", "way three", "en"));
myCollectionA.add(new Banner("r03", "cami tres", "ca"));
myCollectionA.add(new Banner("r02", "cami dos", "ca"));
myCollectionA.add(new Banner("r04", "cami quatre", "ca"));
```

Obtengo las listas separadas, una que lang concide con `es`y la otra con `ca`

```
List<Banner> listOne = myCollectionA.stream().filter(p -> p.getLang().equals("es")).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Banner> listTwo = myCollectionA.stream().filter(p -> p.getLang().equals("ca")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Para unir las listas

```
List<Banner> newList = Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), listTwo.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Obtengo lo siguiente:**

```
row: Banner{ref='r01', src='camino uno', lang='es'}
row: Banner{ref='r02', src='camino dos', lang='es'}
row: Banner{ref='r03', src='camino tres', lang='es'}
row: Banner{ref='r03', src='cami tres', lang='ca'}
row: Banner{ref='r02', src='cami dos', lang='ca'}
row: Banner{ref='r04', src='cami quatre', lang='ca'}
```

Me gustaría combinar las listas mediante `ref` por defecto cogiera la primera lista y si existe la referencia en la segunda que la remplazca y si en la primera no existe la referencia de la segunda que la añade.

Es decir como un sistema de traducción, que la lista parte de `es` si existe en `ca` que la remplazca, añadiendo la novedades de la segunda lista.

**El resultado deseado**

```
row: Banner{ref='r01', src='camino uno', lang='es'}
row: Banner{ref='r02', src='cami dos', lang='ca'}
row: Banner{ref='r03', src='cami tres', lang='ca'}
row: Banner{ref='r04', src='cami quatre', lang='ca'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que se me ocurrió para llegar al resultado deseado fue utilizar el método estático [`comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) de la interfaz [*Comparator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Para ello creo dos instancias: una que compare por el campo `ref` y otra por el campo `lang` de la siguiente forma:

```
Comparator<Banner> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Banner::getRef);
Comparator<Banner> comparatorLang = Comparator.comparing(Banner::getLang);
```

Seguido los utilizo llamando el método `sorted` y `filter` este último recibe el constructor [`TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-) de la clase [*TreeSet*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

```
final List<Banner> collect = Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), listTwo.stream())
    .sorted(comparatorLang)
    .filter(new TreeSet<>(comparator)::add)
    .sorted(comparator)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

```
[
    Banner{ref='r01', src='camino uno', lang='es'}, 
    Banner{ref='r02', src='cami dos', lang='ca'}, 
    Banner{ref='r03', src='cami tres', lang='ca'}, 
    Banner{ref='r04', src='cami quatre', lang='ca'}
]
```